# React hook form. add className to input field on error

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Using "react hook form" is there a way to add a className, like "is-invalid" to the input field who has errors?

This is the code:

```
<div className="form-floating mb-4">
  <input 
    type="email"
    className="form-control is-invalid" 
    id="floatingInput"
    placeholder="name@example.com"
    {...register("email", { required: true, pattern: /\S+@\S+\.\S+/ })}
  />
  <label htmlFor="floatingInput">Email address</label>

  <div className="invalid-feedback">
    {errors.email?.type === 'required' && <span> This field is required</span>}
    {errors.email?.type === 'pattern' && <span> Invalid email</span>}
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get `errors` from `formState` (https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/formstate#main). Then in the `className` you can check if there is an error in `errors.email` and use classes that you want accordingly. E.g.:

```
<input className={errors.email ? 'form-control is-invalid': 'form-control'} ... />
```

Comment: Thanks @L. Letovanec , works fine

Answer (score 2):

You can check if your input has errors like this: `isInvalid = Boolean(errors.email)`. So you can write: `className={classnames("form-control", errors.email && "is-invalid")}`.

[classnames](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames) is the npm module for joining class names.